# Programmatically apply media query without changing iframe size

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, media-queries

I have a small iframe which houses a larger content page.  The iframe has overflow: scroll so you can scroll around and see the entire content page, however, the content page css has media queries which are getting triggered because of the iframe's small size, even though the actual page is much larger.

Is there a way to either manually pick when to apply these query styles or trick the iframe into thinking it's the full width of the content without actually changing its size?

The only option I've thought of is to break the media queries into separate files and programmatically change an additional link's href to point at them as needed, but that seems kind of messy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you've got the right idea. Detect whether you're within an iframe or not and then accordingly append the mediaquery stylesheets.

Comment: The problem with that is that all of that css can be customized and changed by the user, so I'd have to dynamically break it into separate files any time something changed which seems like a lot of work.  Being able to trick the iframe into thinking it was a different size would be much simpler and cleaner if it's possible.